# Using D3 to compute a spline for resampling

Tags: d3.js

I have an array of discrete points that I am plotting in a line chart. D3 is handling the interpolation of the discrete data points to create a smooth line.

E.g.

```
var data = [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0];
var line = d3.svg.area()
                    .x(function (d, i) { return i * lineWidth })
                    .y1(function (d, i) { return h - hOf(d) })
                    .y0(h)
                    .interpolate("cardinal")
                    .data(data);
```

Necessarily, somewhere in the bowels of d3, a cardinal spline function is being computed with the data I gave it as control points.

I would like to recover that spline function so that I can resample my data based on that spline.

It would look something like this:

```
var spline = line.getSpline();
var sample = spline(3.3);
```

Does d3 expose its spline function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spline function is not exposed, but depending on what you want, you may be able to get the information from the line/area. That is, calling `line(x)` gives you the value at position `x`.

Comment: Thanks Lars. I noticed that `line([x])` gives me a path annotation which would be suitable for addition to an svg path's `d` attr, but it's a bit messy to clean that up. If that's the best of what d3 exposes, I'll use another linear algebra library to compute my own spline and take over the job myself.

Comment: You can always modify the source, but this is what's exposed by default.